# HTML/CSS: background overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay, background-image, css-position

I have a background `<div>` that is positioned in the middle of the page.
Above this I have a `<div>` with a text inside.

If the page is viewed in fullscreen, everything seems fine.
But if the page is viewed in a small window, the text disappears.

How can I make the text always staying in the front?

**Code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w2T79/

**Images:**

"normal view:" http://www.suckmypic.net/26632/83735f21.png

"small view:" http://www.suckmypic.net/26633/7be8fc00.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the parent-div an id ('container' for example), then add the code below to your CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

.txt {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Maybe you can provide us a link to the page you are working on, because in jsFiddle only 'text' is visible, and no image.

Comment: `z-index` and `position: relative` on text element will do the trick. The problem was that background div HTML code is placed after the text, so browser implicitly decide that background should stay on top.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have a `margin-top` of 70 px and the upper div disappears under the backgroud.

Do a `position: relative` and an `high z-index` and you get what you want

Answer (score 0):

This you can achieve by giving `position:relative;z-index:1000;` to `<p>` tag.
Check here:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2T79/4/
Hope you want in this way.